# HTML5 / CSS3 center 2 items horizontally and vertically in a row

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, css

I have 2 items: a calendar component, and a button. They are different height/width.

How do I center them horizontally and vertically in a row?

Table? Div? ...

I am thinking each object has 50% of the area and is centered in that. However, I might be open to centering them (with a gap in between each other) horizontally. Then centering them vertically as a pair.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on centering vertically, but typically when you want to center a tag you give it the style of margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bpkH4/. Some of the CSS is purely decorative.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #btn
    {
        background-color:#FF0000;
        width:100px;
        height:30px;
    }

    #comp
    {
        background-color:#00FFFF;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }

    #container
    {
        width:500px;
        height:300px;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;           

        text-align:center;
    }

    .contain
    {

        background-color:#AAAAAA;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .elem
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin:auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="contain">
            <div class="elem" id="comp">Component in Here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contain">        
            <div class="elem" id="btn">Button</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmmm. Works in Firefox but not IE9.

Comment: @ginalster You probably need to add the HTML5 doctype: <!DOCTYPE html>. I didn't include that in the example above.

Comment: hmmm, seems to work fine now in jsfiddle in IE. Not working in VS2012 partial view b ut probably because it is nested in <div>s and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a container div and set a margin: 0 auto; on each to center them horizontally. You can also center the container horizontally on the page using the same technique.

[CSS Horizontal Align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

[Centering: Auto-width Margins](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html)

For the vertical centering of the container:

[6 Methods For Vertical Centering With CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)